# How to program the quadratic formula (without simplifying the roots) on a ti83 plus?

Tags: calculator, quadratic

First of all, I apologize if this isn't the correct website to ask this question on.

I know how to program the basic formula, but is it possible to program the formula to not simplify the roots? (so as to avoid irrational numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You could just do the 2 calculations seperatly as the quadratic formula is a fraction. My answer is in pseudocode.

[image: Quadratic Formula]

`f` and `g` are the top parts, `e` is the bottom part of the equation. `a`, `b` and `c` are the inputs.

```
 e <- 2*a
 f <- -b + sqrt(b^2-4*a*c)
 g <- -b - sqrt(b^2-4*a*c)

 Pretty Print Here
```

Once you have them like that you could print them out as shown in the line below. I am not exactly sure how to pretty print in ti-basic. But it would like something like the below.

```
disp f,"/",e
disp g,"/",e
```

All you have to figure out how to get it to print on one line for each `disp`. You could also use `output`.